# Не ставится точка на карте mapkit

Tags: android, kotlin, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit, mapkit

При нажатии на карту не ставится точка на карте андройд приложения. Проект пишется на kotlin.

```
val inputListener = object : InputListener {
        override fun onMapTap(map: Map, point: Point) {
            val worldPoint = point
            map.mapObjects.addPlacemark().apply {
                if (worldPoint != null) {
                    geometry = worldPoint
                    setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(this@MeetingDetailActivity, R.drawable.point))
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onMapLongTap(map: Map, point: Point) {
        }
    }
```

```
override fun onStart() {
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapview)
        mapView.mapWindow.map.move(CameraPosition(
            Point(55.751225, 37.629540),
            /* zoom = */ 17.0f,
            /* azimuth = */ 150.0f,
            /* tilt = */ 30.0f
        ))
        val centerX = mapView.mapWindow.width() / 2f
        val centerY = mapView.mapWindow.height() / 2f
        val centerPoint = ScreenPoint(centerX, centerY)
// For example, worldPoint = (59.935493, 30.327392)
        val worldPoint1 = mapView.mapWindow.screenToWorld(centerPoint)
        mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark().apply {
            if (worldPoint1 != null) {
                geometry = worldPoint1
            }
            setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(this@MeetingDetailActivity, R.drawable.point))
        }

        mapView.mapWindow.map.addInputListener(inputListener)

        super.onStart()
        mapView.onStart()
    }
```

Comment: Для полноценного анализа нужен минимальный рабочий пример кода. Если нет возможности выложить его в доступ с предоставлением публичной ссылки, можно обратиться напрямую в поддержку сервиса по почте maps-api@support.yandex.ru